# Найти уязвимость: на картинку удаленно наложили объекты

Tags: изображения, php

Здравствуйте!

У меня такая проблема: на картинку удаленно наложили еще пару объектов. Я не могу понять с чего начинать искать уязвимость. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался с подобным?

Вот ссылка на сайт: http://www.uniorextrim.ru/index.php?tab=news&post_id=3 
(На картинке сразу поймете какой объект лишний)
[image]

Comment: резиновая лодка или палатка ?

Comment: Вы немного не так поняли, резиновая лодка и палатки это было все, из лишнего здесь только "резинка" и какая-то хрень между палаткой и спальником.... Остальные картинки я для массовки накидал сам....

Comment: какая-то хрень это "бульбулятор" или бонг http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Бонг

Comment: по моему лишнее тут презик :) Хотя, конечно, кто как отдыхает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего утечка пароля на Вашем ftp, поменяйте пароль и картинку для начала

Comment: ах да, и ни кому больше не говорите пароль.

Comment: спасибо! попробую так сделать... может быть еще у кого нибудь  какие то варианты будут?

Comment: Возьмите за правило менять пароли в таких случаях. А лучше вообще, с определенным интервалом менять для большей надежности. И никому, никому не сообщайте свой пароль, даже администрации хостинга. Им ваш пароль не нужен, чтобы получить доступ к вашему серверу

Comment: Спасибо, уже поменял все пароли и буду теперь менять периодически. 

Но все же, есть ли другие способы реализации подобного. Что то типа: парсинга папки, затем с помощью PHP или еще чего нибудь наложить на картинку другое изображение и сохранить опять же в эту папку? 

Это я к тому, что может быть у меня привилегии на папке стоят все открытые, т.е. доступна для чтения и записи, и т.д. И этот "Чертила" воспользовался этим моментом? Но с другой стороны, если она будет недоступна для чтения и записи, я ведь и сам не смогу туда изображения добавлять...

Comment: > Но все же, есть ли другие способы реализации подобного. 

После каждого обновления считайте какой-нибудь хэш (md5, например) для всех файлов сайта и сохраняйте их в список в отдельную секретную папку :). Можно периодически сравнивать хэши существующих файлов с эталонными и если что-то изменилось - поднимать тревогу.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Попробую разобраться как это сделать...